# Calendar API Login Required, Access key

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, calendar

I'm getting the login required error and i'm thinking that i'm not sending the accessToken properly, and i don't know how to send it properly.

**App\Provider\GoogleClientServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class GoogleClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    function register(){
        /* Get config variables */
        $service_account_name = getenv('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME');
        $key_file_location = base_path() . getenv('GOOGLE_KEY_FILE_LOCATION');

        $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
        /* Add the scopes you need */
        $scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];

        $client = new \Google_Client();

        $client->setAuthConfigFile('/resources/assets/client_secret.json');

        $cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_account_name,
            $scopes,
            $key
        );


        $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

        // repeat this block for as many Google_Services_* as you like
        // don't forget to add scopes for other services.
        $this->app->singleton(\Google_Service_Calendar::class, function ($app) use ($client) {
            return new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        });
    }

}
```

**App\http\AgendaController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Google_Service_Calendar;
use App\kosten;
use App\User;

class AgendaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Google_Service_Calendar $client){
      $calendarList = $client->calendarList->listCalendarList();
      dd($calendarList->getItems());
    }  

    public function index()
    {


      return view('agenda');
    }
}
```

Added to .env

GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME=SERVICEACCOUNTNAME@cogent-sunspot-159410.iam.gserviceaccount.com
GOOGLE_KEY_FILE_LOCATION=/resources/assets/key.p12

Comment: Can you please provide the error message that you are getting?

Comment: @jojonas 
`
Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 118:
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "Login Required",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Login Required"
}
}`

Comment: Make sure your `getenv` are returning something.

Comment: @EddyTheDove It does infact return the proper service account and key.p12